Dagster sensor-daemon starts jobs on its own
I created a job for dagster in which I wrote the print() functions to check that it is working, but dagster itself launches it once a minute and my prints are output to the console.
triggered_jobs.py
from dagster import job
@job
def MY_JOB():
    print("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-/-/-/-=/-=/-=-_?+?+")    
    print("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-/-/-/-=/-=/-=-_?+?+")
    print("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-/-/-/-=/-=/-=-_?+?+")
    print("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-/-/-/-=/-=/-=-_?+?+")
    print("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-/-/-/-=/-=/-=-_?+?+")
    print("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-/-/-/-=/-=/-=-_?+?+")
    print("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-/-/-/-=/-=/-=-_?+?+")  

init.py
defs = Definitions(
    assets=(
        assets1 +
        assets2 +
        []
    ),
    jobs=[
        job1,
        job2,
        MY_JOB,
    ],
    ...

In Dagster's UI these runs are not displayed and show that last run: none
I tried to run only dagster-daemon (dagster-daemon run command) and realized that it executes my job every minute and twice at startup. What can be done about this and why does it do this?
